# Override JQuery functions (logging decorator)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to create a logging decorator around jQuery function but it is called only once (in initialization time). How to fix it? Please look at the code.

```
function makeLogging(f) {

  function wrapper(...rest) {
      console.log(f.name);
      console.log(rest);
      return f.apply(this, rest);
    }

  return wrapper;
}

const task = $('.task');

task.on = makeLogging(task.on);

task.on('click', () => console.log('hi'));
```

The click event does not display messages about the called function.

Comment: Use `$(task).on(...)`

Comment: I use `$(task).on(...)` but I need wrap this function on logging decorator. I need to get information that this function was called, with what arguments it was called and on which selector.This is not necessarily a function `on`, but it's definitely the jQuery functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code example of answer

```
function makeLogging(f) {

  function auxiliaryWrapper(x, rest) {
    return () => {
      console.log(f.name);
      console.log(rest);
      x();
    }
  }

  function mainWrapper(...rest) {
      const restWithWrap = rest.map(arg => {
        if (typeof arg === 'function') {
          return auxiliaryWrapper(arg,rest);
        }
        return arg;
      });
      console.log(restWithWrap);
      return f.apply(this, restWithWrap);
  }

  return mainWrapper;
}

const task = $('.task');

task.on = makeLogging(task.on);

task.on('click', () => console.log('hi'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it a little bit wrong, if I caught the idea what you want to achieve. For functionality, you described, please try following:

```
task.on('click', makeLogging(() => console.log('hi')));
```

In your original code, you wrapped the functionality of `on()` function, but this `on()` function is not called as event handler - it only install actual event handler. That's why logging is called only once during installation of the handler.

Comment: I want to know about actual event handler (`on` etc) information. Every time this function is called, I need all the information about calling it

Comment: Ok, but  `on` etc. are not an actual event handler. In your case  `() => console.log(‘hi’)` is the actual event handler. This is why your decorator is called only once - you installed decorator for  `on` function and this function was really called only once, when you issued  `task.on(‘click’, () => console.log(‘hi’));` command.

Comment: Yes, I understood it yesterday and resolved. Now I have the worked code. Thanks for help